# Why don't public organizations support Web Mercator EPSG 3857 for WMS?

Tags: wms, map-service, web-mercator

Given that Web Mercator is the defacto standard for web mapping and all basemaps (Google, ESRI, Mapbox) are based on this coordinate system..

Why do many organizations e.g. NOAA not publish their WMS with support for Web Mercator ?

For example, this WMS https://idpgis.ncep.noaa.gov/arcgis/services/NWS_Forecasts_Guidance_Warnings/watch_warn_adv/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

only supports EPSG 4326 (WGS84) and 4269 (NAD83).

To get this service to overly with a Web Mercator basemap, the service needs to be re-projected on-the-fly, something that only seems possible with desktop GIS tools.

My understanding is that adding support for additional coordinate systems is simply a matter of adding them to the list when the service is published.

Is this really such a burden/consumer of resources to do ?

Comment: WMS reprojection can be done within a webmap... https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/raster-reprojection.html

Comment: @Ian Turton: This is a valid question that is NOT opinion-based. NOAA published its official advisory regarding the use of Web Mercator here http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/web_mercator/index.html

Comment: The problem with Web Mercator is that it erroneously applied Spherical Mercator projection on ellipsoidal coordinates without first doing any latitude conversion (eg to isomorphic). The end result is that Web Mercator is NOT conformal, hence its rhumblines are flawed.